# App is crashing while using view flipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am recently developed an app which uses the view flipper in android. Everything is working fine but I did not get something. Should I pause the flipping when ever I minimize my app to reduce the load or it automatically pauses.

Comment: logcat will give some more information